# Range of values of $R^2$ for a two-feature linear model based on the $R^2$s of one-feature linear models?

Tags: self-study, linear-model

I was asked this in an interview. You have two features, $x_1$ and $x_2$. You fit a simple linear model on each feature, so

$$
\underbrace{y = x_1 \beta}_{\text{model 1}}, \qquad \underbrace{y = x_2 \beta}_{\text{model 2}}.
$$

You compute the $R^2$ value for each model and find that each one has an $R^2$ of $0.1$. Now you fit a model on *both* features

$$
y = x_1 \beta_1 + x_2 \beta_2.
$$

What range of values can you expect this model's $R^2$ to take? I was stumped and am curious how to reason through this.

Comment: Between 0.1 and 0.2

Comment: Please add the `[self-study]` tag & read its 
[wiki](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info). Can you find a lower bound to the $R^2$ of the larger model?

Comment: @user158565 please give an explanation of how how got that answer.

Comment: Is it important that both models have no intercept (or the same intercept)?

Comment: @user158565 To see why that answer might be wrong, consider the $(x_1,x_2,y)$ dataset $(1,2.1,2),$ $(3,6.1,0)$ and bear in mind these models explicitly have no intercepts.  I chose these data to conform to the assumptions, but since $X_1$ and $X_2$ are linearly independent, $R^2$ for the full model is $1.$

Comment: @whuber The data in your current example is 2 x 3. Could you create one that is 3 x 3?

Comment: @user158565 Sure--but there's no need to, because a counterexample is a counterexample.  If you like, just duplicate one of the observations. That will change the individual $R^2$ values, but not by enough to make a difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple approach to this problem is considering it from a geometrical view of point.

Firstly, we immediately know answer is within range [0.1, 1], then let's check if it's tight.

Note regression is projection of $y$ on to column space of $x$.

If vector $x_1$ and $x_2$ are almost perfect linear dependent, it's easy to see the projection of $y$ is almost the same as before, thus $R^2$ is almost 0.1.

If $y$ lies in subspace by two vector $x_1$ and $x_2$(this indeed can happen, you can first think of it in 3-dim space, then it holds for general n-dim space), then we immediately know $R^2$ is 1.

Thus answer should be (0.1, 1].